# How to write SQL in a migration in Rails

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, rails-activerecord

I have the following SQL which I need to do

```
CREATE TABLE cars_users2 AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM cars_users;

DROP TABLE cars_users;

ALTER TABLE cars_users2 RENAME TO cars_users;
```

since I cannot use heroku dataclips to drop a table, I cannot use dataclips.

So I guess I need to do this in a migration.

How do I write this sql as a migration?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

For your up migration:

```
execute "CREATE TABLE cars_users2 AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM cars_users;" 
drop_table :car_users  
rename_table :car_users2, :car_users
```

and for down:

```
raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
```

Full migration:

```
class TheMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def up
        execute "CREATE TABLE cars_users2 AS SELECT DISTINCT * from cars_users;" 
        drop_table :car_users  
        rename_table :car_users2, :car_users  
    end

    def down
        raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
    end
end
```

Answer (score 24):

You could try to use the [`execute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/AbstractMysqlAdapter.html#method-i-execute) method.

Something like this (it's untested, some kind of brainchild)

```
class UpdateCarUserTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute "CREATE TABLE cars_users2 AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM cars_users"
    execute "DROP TABLE cars_users"
    execute "ALTER TABLE cars_users2 RENAME TO cars_users"
  end
```

As there is no equivalent `down` method, an `ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration` should be raised when trying to migrate down.

Answer (score 11):

In case you  need to use `change` instead of `up` and `down` you can use `reversible`.
It works on Rails 4 or above.

```
class ExampleMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :distributors do |t|
      t.string :zipcode
    end

    reversible do |dir|
      dir.up do
        # add a CHECK constraint
        execute <<-SQL
          ALTER TABLE distributors
            ADD CONSTRAINT zipchk
              CHECK (char_length(zipcode) = 5) NO INHERIT;
        SQL
      end
      dir.down do
        execute <<-SQL
          ALTER TABLE distributors
            DROP CONSTRAINT zipchk
        SQL
      end
    end

    add_column :users, :home_page_url, :string
    rename_column :users, :email, :email_address
  end
end
```

Sources: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-reversible

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Migration/reversible

Answer (score 10):

I prefer here doc:

```
execute <<-SQL
  CREATE TABLE cars_users2 AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM cars_users;
  DROP TABLE cars_users;
  ALTER TABLE cars_users2 RENAME TO cars_users;
SQL
```

**notice:**
This only works for  *PostgreSQL*, if you are using MySQL you should set [CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-real-connect.html) for the adapter.

Comment: Why do you prefer this?

Comment: Setting CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS is a serious security risk re: SQL injection. That's why it's off by default.