# Rails migration. Cast integer values into boolean with change_column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-migration

I'm using RoR5 with PostgreSQL. I have a table with a column `status`. Which is of a type integer and holds three values 0, 1, 2. Those values represent three statuses `allowed`, `not_allowed` and `no_tests`.

I'm gonna change the logic. I want to convert two statuses `allowed` and `not_allowed` into `boolean`. Then I'll create a separate column for the `no_tests`.

Right now I have this accordance:
`enum status: %i[allowed not_allowed no_tests]`.

How should I write a migration to have `allowed` as `true` and both `not_allowed` and `no_tests` as `false` in the changed column?

Comment: @user1023110 After reading this article https://robots.thoughtbot.com/data-migrations-in-rails I think I will stick to your approach. It really smells bad to manipulate data in migration. Please answer and I will accept the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is two separate operations (change table structure, convert existing data), only one of would typically be done in a migration. If I were you I would first run a migration to add the new status column, and then do an update either in sql if you have easy access to the postgres console or at the rails console to recode the existing data in your new column. After you've recoded the data you can drop the old columns in another migration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need some stuff in `up` method within migration.

```
def up
  add_column :table_name, :status2, :boolean
  Loop on each element of model check for status and update status2
  remove_column :table_name, :status
  rename_column :table_name, :status2, :status
end
```

You can also go with case statement in update [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15766129/3759158) It will help. You can put your query in migration as well something similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14857060/3759158).

You can also do one more thing like :
 1. Make migration to add new column.
 2. Make rake task to populate data.
 3. Make one more migration to delete old column and rename newly added column.

**Update :** For better understanding on migration do read [this article](https://railsguides.net/change-data-in-migrations-like-a-boss/).

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know it's possible to do things like that in a migration. Is there any documentation on that? Thanks @Manishh

Comment: @IlliaKuzma I have update my answer with document link.